# Image looks bad when testing, but original image file is looking just fine

Tags: ios, uiimageview

Why does my image look awful when I'm testing the app on my 5s. It also looks awful when testing it on the simulator. My image has the same width as the 5s: 640px. It is saved as @2x. The UIImageView has the exact same size as the image: 640. The UIImageView is also keeping the view in ratio.

[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lnu7s.jpg)

I'm trying to archive the same quality result as shown in the second image, which is screenshotted from a random relevant app.

[The quality I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLhmc.jpg)

I can't add the original image file because I need 10 reputation for another link. But I can assure you that the original image file looks just fine. So somewhere in Xcode there is going something wrong?

Comment: Are you sure your imageView height is the same as the image ? Also, why do you set your `UIImageView` width to 640 ? It should be 320, because the width is measured in points and not in pixels.

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo Actually the UIImageView does have a locked ratio, and is pinned to both sides. But it's the exact same ratio as the image.

Comment: Well that's weird. Can you provide a sample test project in order to reproduce it ?

Comment: for the sake of testing, dont use xasset for now. instead, drag the image to the project, now call the image 'test' (change its name from the on in the xasset so you wont conflict) and try to load it, what are the results?

Comment: @MichaëlAzevedo
I think something is messed up with the UIImageView. The image looks fine in another view controller. I'm now trying to delete the existing UIImageViews and add them again.

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the line below fixed it:

```
self.Aktau1?.layer.shouldRasterize = true
```

Without that line, my code now looks like this (to apply a shadow):

```
self.Aktau1?.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
self.Aktau1?.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.15
self.Aktau1?.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 45                           
self.Aktau1?.layer.shadowRadius = 25
```